# mysqli_query returns NULL on host but works on local host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have small php web service and I tested it locally and it works. When I uploaded it to bluehost server I get NULL as a result from calling `mysqli_query`

```
$con = connect();
    $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $userName);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);

    $query1 = "select * from `users` where `user_name` = '$userName'";

    $res1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
//var_dump($res1)  prints NULL

    if ($res1) {
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res1);

        if ($count == 0) {
            $query2 = "select * from `users` where `email` = '$email'";
            $res2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
            if ($res2) {
                $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($res2);
                if ($count2 == 0) {
                    return 0; //not found before
                } else {
                    return 2; //Email already exists
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 1; //user name already exists
        }
    } else {
        return -1;   //Database Error; // always resturned
    }
```

Edit 1: //Code to connect to database
function connect() {

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $con;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
If I added `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` in the first line at connect() method, I got nothing at all, even the -1 return is not there.

Comment: add your code that connect with the database

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/bind-param-between-environment/22662582#22662582

Comment: @OfirH added to the quest

Comment: @YourCommonSense , not a duplicate. I tried the code there did not work for me.

Comment: it is not for "trying". it have to be always used.

Comment: beside that, you have to have the general idea on PHP errors.

Comment: Thanks @YourCommonSense . But when I added it, no errors shown at all. If I removed it, I get this -1 , if added that line, nothing at all.

Comment: no errors are shown because your PHP configured so

Comment: you have to have at least a slight idea on getting in touch with programming errors

Comment: on a live server, for example, they shouldn't be shown

Comment: instead, they are logged in a log file

Comment: so, they won't bug site users

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm not a php developer in the first place, but Android, I came across this issue when connecting to that script from my mobile app and I'm trying to fix. but you are right anyway.

Comment: yet let a programmer to see them all, without the need to stand behind every user's shoulder

Comment: Why you are saying that ?!. I'm a programmer but for different platform and I have basic knowledge of php so I'm trying to solve a problem in a place where people helps others to do. If you can't help, so do not waste your time here.

Comment: you might try to var_dump $con right after your first line. You aren't testing the return value for the case where the connection fails. I suspect it's 0 which makes the mysqli_query() call very unhappy.

Comment: @RobP I did and it returns 2 objects of mysqli like this object(mysqli)#1 (19) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(6) "5.5.36"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50536)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in the database structure and I don't know why mySqli did not show this when I print the error messages. I imported the sql dump file and it worked. Sorry and Thanks for your time.